# Matplotlib plot is a no-show

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

When I run this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def add_prop(group):
    births = group.births.astype(float)
    group['prop'] = births/births.sum()
    return group

pieces = []
columns = ['name', 'sex', 'births']

for year in range(1880, 2012):
    path = 'yob%d.txt' % year
    frame = pd.read_csv(path, names = columns)
    frame['year'] = year
    pieces.append(frame)
    names = pd.concat(pieces, ignore_index = True)

total_births = names.pivot_table('births', rows = 'year', cols = 'sex', aggfunc = sum)
total_births.plot(title = 'Total Births by sex and year')
```

I get no plot.  This is from Wes McKinney's book on using Python for data analysis.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you're using ipython (and you should be!), you can use the pylab flag: `ipython --pylab`

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Put

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

at the top, and

```
plt.show()
```

at the end.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this happens? It's fine without on one computer, but required elsewhere

Comment: @NoelEvans: Inside a GUI such as an IPython notebook, you may not need to call `plt.show()` depending on how the GUI is configured. If you run the Python script from the command line, then you would have to call `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 31):

In the IPython notebook you could also use `%matplotlib inline` at the top of the notebook to automatically display the created plots in the output cells.

Answer (score 2):

your code is correct.
just put:

```
import matplotlib as plt
```

for displaying your plot:

```
plt.show()
```