# Displaying numpy matrix in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Let's say I have a numpy matrix of shape (200, 100). Call it `input`. I want to display it in matplotlib, using different colors for different ranges of values. Here is what I tried to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

pyplot.matshow(input, cmap=pyplot.cm.hot)
```

However, when I ran the code, nothing appeared. Where did I go wrong?

I use Python 2.7, if that is relevant. New to Python, so please be gentle :-)

**EDIT:**

I have also tried `pyplot.show(input)`, but that did not work either.

Comment: Try to call `pyplot.show()`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16522380/190597

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to run:

```
pyplot.show()
```

after `pyplot.matshow` execution.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify you want to see images directly in you notebook. 
If you don't want to write `pyplot.show()` after each plot you need, just add pylab inline option after the pyplot import

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
%pylab inline
```

Comment: Awesome! I did not know this. Thank you.